# Array of arrays format issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have the following [data format](http://jsfiddle.net/s6P37/) (stored in variable `matrixData`):

```
{
    "header": ["Date", "Total", "Breakdown"],
    "data": [
        [
            "2014-06-05",
            5340,
            {
                "header": ["BookingCount", "LastYearDifference"],
                "data": [[506, 46], [524, 34], [448, 25]]
            }
        ],
        [
            "2014-06-06",
            14339,
            {
                "header": ["BookingCount", "LastYearDifference"],
                "data": [[506, 46], [432, 92], [498, 37]]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

which I would need to change to something that I can pass through the following function from Google Charts:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
}
```

I would then pass that data inside the following template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tableContent">
      <tr>
        <td data-content="Date"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount0"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount1"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount2"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount3"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="Total"></td>
      </tr>
</script>
```

This would be a weekly report so that template would repeated 7 times.

I am trying to use the following function but no success:

```
function generateObject(){

    var newarray = [],
        thing;

    for(var y = 1; y < matrixData.Data.length; y++){
        thing = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < matrixData.Data[0].length; i++){
            if (i > 0) {
              thing[matrixData.Data[0][i]] = matrixData.Data[y][i];
            }
        }
        newarray.push(thing);
    }

    return newarray;
}
```

Comment: `matrixData.Data[y]`?

Comment: You must include your desired output data model. Posting a function with a nested loop together with "no success" is not enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps because the function is `arrayToDataTable` and not `arrayWithObjectsToDataTable`. 
The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable) states:

> This method does not support [...] use of the JavaScript literal cell object with f or v values: {v: 3.0, f: 'Three'}. If you need to specify custom cell values, or a formatted value, or Date/DateTime value, use DataTable.addRow()/DataTable.addRows() or DataTable.setValue().

So the solution would be to either use `DataTable.addRow()` or change `thing` to be an array and push your values into it.
As for the `keys` in your object's key value pairs, the documentation says:

> If opt_firstRowIsData is false (the default), the first row will be interpreted as header labels

So simply push your headers in as the first array.